# How to pass arguments to build() in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I have written a code with GridLayout which need to be added with buttons in Python file. So, the add_widget() mainpulation should be done in build(). I am getting errors and couldn't get it.Someone Please help me.

In short, instead of add_btn(), I need it in build() of MineApp class.
 Thanks in advance.`

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class MainLayout(BoxLayout):
    def build(self):
        pass
    def add_btn(self,id):
        for i in range(100):
            id.add_widget(Button())
class MineApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MineApp().run()
```

mine.kv file:

```
<MainLayout>:
    orientation:'vertical'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'horizontal'
        height: '30px'
        size_hint_y:None
        TextInput:
            id: tinput
            text:'10'
        Button:
            text:'start'
            on_press:root.add_btn(grid)
        Label:
            id:mylabel
            text:'0'
    GridLayout:
        id: grid
        cols:10
        rows:10
```

Answer (score 0):

It took some time but think I get what you're trying to say! You can get the same effect by passing the id parameter of Grid in the .py file like so...

```
class MainLayout(BoxLayout):
    def build(self):
        for i in range(100):
            self.ids.grid.add_widget(Button())
```

Then, you can just take your start button and...

```
Button:
    text:'start'
    on_press:root.build()
```

This works because "self" in .py refers to the class while in the .kv a similar wording would be 'root' (while 'self' in .kv refers to the widget!) Is this what you kind of had in mind? Let me know! I tried it out myself and had no problem running it through :)

Also, it wasn't put explicitly here that to test the code you'd need to import Builder via:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
```

and do...

```
Builder.load_file("mine.kv")
```

as your .py and .kv don't share the same name (which you'd still need to add a "#File name: main.py" to the .kv if they did match names! Other than that, it looks good!

Comment: Your code worked perfectly but what happens is the buttons are added only when I click the start button. Else if it is present in build()  the buttons will be created automatically when the activity is created instead of waiting for a button press. Any ideas? and thanks